# Resizing an image in asp.net without losing the image quality

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, image-scaling

I am developing an ASP.NET 3.5 web application in which I am allowing my users to upload either jpeg,gif,bmp or png images. If the uploaded image dimensions are greater then 103 x 32 the I want to resize the uploaded image to 103 x 32. I have read some blog posts and articles, and have also tried some of the code samples but nothing seems to work right. Has anyone succeed in doing this?

Comment: Post the code you are using that doesn't work, and explain in which way it does not work.

Comment: You want to force 103x32? Or best fit?

Comment: `ImageBuilder.Current.Build(HttpPostedFile file, string path, new ResizeSettings("width=103&height=32"));`  //Using the [Image Resizer library](http://imageresizing.net)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I had the same problem a while back and dealt with it this way:

```
private Image RezizeImage(Image img, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
{
    if(img.Height < maxHeight && img.Width < maxWidth) return img;
    using (img)
    {
        Double xRatio = (double)img.Width / maxWidth;
        Double yRatio = (double)img.Height / maxHeight;
        Double ratio = Math.Max(xRatio, yRatio);
        int nnx = (int)Math.Floor(img.Width / ratio);
        int nny = (int)Math.Floor(img.Height / ratio);
        Bitmap cpy = new Bitmap(nnx, nny, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(cpy))
        {
            gr.Clear(Color.Transparent);

            // This is said to give best quality when resizing images
            gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

            gr.DrawImage(img,
                new Rectangle(0, 0, nnx, nny),
                new Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height),
                GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }
        return cpy;
    }

}

private MemoryStream BytearrayToStream(byte[] arr)
{
    return new MemoryStream(arr, 0, arr.Length);
}

private void HandleImageUpload(byte[] binaryImage)
{
    Image img = RezizeImage(Image.FromStream(BytearrayToStream(binaryImage)), 103, 32);
    img.Save("IMAGELOCATION.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
}
```

I just read that this was the the way to get highest quality.

Comment: In a new version I also take into account that I won't strech the images, but that should be fairly easy to work out :-P (hint: `ration = Math.Min(ration, 1.0);`)

Comment: Well, there are a [few more settings that will help](http://nathanaeljones.com/163/20-image-resizing-pitfalls/), such as pixel offset.

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately, the results I see from this has blurry top and left edges when I scaled a large (3264 x 2448) image down to 60 x 45.

Comment: This is a great solution.  Be aware that PropertyInfo is empty after you run it though.  So if you are planning to rotate the image to be upright, do that first.

Answer (score 41):

This is the code I use. It supports rotation, and also sets the image resolution to the JPEG standards of 72dpi@24-bit color (by default GDI+ saves images at 96dpi@32-bit color). It also fixes the black/gray border problem that some people experience when resizing images.

```
/// <summary>
/// Resizes and rotates an image, keeping the original aspect ratio. Does not dispose the original
/// Image instance.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="image">Image instance</param>
/// <param name="width">desired width</param>
/// <param name="height">desired height</param>
/// <param name="rotateFlipType">desired RotateFlipType</param>
/// <returns>new resized/rotated Image instance</returns>
public static Image Resize(Image image, int width, int height, RotateFlipType rotateFlipType)
{
    // clone the Image instance, since we don't want to resize the original Image instance
    var rotatedImage = image.Clone() as Image;
    rotatedImage.RotateFlip(rotateFlipType);
    var newSize = CalculateResizedDimensions(rotatedImage, width, height);

    var resizedImage = new Bitmap(newSize.Width, newSize.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    resizedImage.SetResolution(72, 72);

    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(resizedImage))
    {
        // set parameters to create a high-quality thumbnail
        graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

        // use an image attribute in order to remove the black/gray border around image after resize
        // (most obvious on white images), see this post for more information:
        // http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/imgresizoutperfgdiplus.aspx
        using (var attribute = new ImageAttributes())
        {
            attribute.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipXY);

            // draws the resized image to the bitmap
            graphics.DrawImage(rotatedImage, new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), newSize), 0, 0, rotatedImage.Width, rotatedImage.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attribute);
        }
    }

    return resizedImage;
}

/// <summary>
/// Calculates resized dimensions for an image, preserving the aspect ratio.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="image">Image instance</param>
/// <param name="desiredWidth">desired width</param>
/// <param name="desiredHeight">desired height</param>
/// <returns>Size instance with the resized dimensions</returns>
private static Size CalculateResizedDimensions(Image image, int desiredWidth, int desiredHeight)
{
    var widthScale = (double)desiredWidth / image.Width;
    var heightScale = (double)desiredHeight / image.Height;

    // scale to whichever ratio is smaller, this works for both scaling up and scaling down
    var scale = widthScale < heightScale ? widthScale : heightScale;

    return new Size
                   {
                       Width = (int) (scale * image.Width),
                       Height = (int) (scale * image.Height)
                   };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing to the solution to the gray border problem.

Comment: This solution resize without change original image colors! Great job!

Comment: Thank you, this solution really helped med. I have combined with other method which prints text on resized image, works excellent.

Comment: This code works good, but in order not to lose the transparency of the image you would have to change `PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb` to `PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb`

Answer (score 2):

The code associated with the actual resizing of the bitmap is as follows.

```
public static Bitmap ResizeBitmap( Bitmap originalBitmap, int requiredHeight, int requiredWidth )
{
   int[] heightWidthRequiredDimensions;

   // Pass dimensions to worker method depending on image type required
   heightWidthRequiredDimensions = WorkDimensions(originalBitmap.Height, originalBitmap.Width, requiredHeight, requiredWidth);


   Bitmap resizedBitmap = new Bitmap( heightWidthRequiredDimensions[1],
                                      heightWidthRequiredDimensions[0] );

   const float resolution = 72;

   resizedBitmap.SetResolution( resolution, resolution );

   Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromImage( (Image) resizedBitmap );

   graphic.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
   graphic.DrawImage( originalBitmap, 0, 0, resizedBitmap.Width, resizedBitmap.Height );

   graphic.Dispose();
   originalBitmap.Dispose();
   //resizedBitmap.Dispose(); // Still in use


   return resizedBitmap;
}


private static int[] WorkDimensions(int originalHeight, int originalWidth, int requiredHeight, int requiredWidth )
{
   int imgHeight = 0;
   int imgWidth = 0;

   imgWidth = requiredHeight;
   imgHeight = requiredWidth;


   int requiredHeightLocal = originalHeight;
   int requiredWidthLocal = originalWidth;

   double ratio = 0;

   // Check height first
   // If original height exceeds maximum, get new height and work ratio.
   if ( originalHeight > imgHeight )
   {
       ratio = double.Parse( ( (double) imgHeight / (double) originalHeight ).ToString() );
       requiredHeightLocal = imgHeight;
       requiredWidthLocal = (int) ( (decimal) originalWidth * (decimal) ratio );
   }

   // Check width second. It will most likely have been sized down enough
   // in the previous if statement. If not, change both dimensions here by width.
   // If new width exceeds maximum, get new width and height ratio.
   if ( requiredWidthLocal >= imgWidth )
   {
       ratio = double.Parse( ( (double) imgWidth / (double) originalWidth ).ToString() );
       requiredWidthLocal = imgWidth;
       requiredHeightLocal = (int) ( (double) originalHeight * (double) ratio );
   }

   int[] heightWidthDimensionArr = { requiredHeightLocal, requiredWidthLocal };

   return heightWidthDimensionArr;
}
}
```

This blog post contains full source code for image resizing, and compression (if required)

http://blog.bombdefused.com/2010/08/bulk-image-optimizer-in-c-full-source.html

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully done this by creating a bitmap of the image and then resizing the bitmap...I'm not sure if this is the best or most efficient way of doing this, but it works for me.

In my case, I needed to cut the height and width of the image by half.

Here's what I did.

```
   private Image getImageFromBytes(byte[] myByteArray)
    {                        
        System.IO.MemoryStream newImageStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(myByteArray, 0, myByteArray.Length);
        Image image = Image.FromStream(newImageStream, true);
        Bitmap resized = new Bitmap(image, image.Width / 2, image.Height / 2);
        image.Dispose();
        newImageStream.Dispose();
        return resized;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static System.Drawing.Image ScaleImage(System.Drawing.Image image, int maxImageHeight)
    {
        /* we will resize image based on the height/width ratio by passing expected height as parameter. Based on Expected height and current image height, new ratio will be arrived and using the same we will do the resizing of image width. */

        var ratio = (double)maxImageHeight / image.Height;
        var newWidth = (int)(image.Width * ratio);
        var newHeight = (int)(image.Height * ratio);
        var newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
        {
            g.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
        }
        return newImage;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  decimal size = Math.Round(((decimal)fUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength / (decimal)1024), 2);
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(MapPath("Images"));
        FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
         foreach (FileInfo info in files)
        {
              decimal size2 = Math.Round(((decimal)info.Length / (decimal)1024), 2);
              string Image_name = info.Name.ToString();
              string targetPath = Server.MapPath("Images/" + Image_name);
              string strm = Server.MapPath("Images/" + Image_name);
              var targetFile = targetPath;
              ReduceImageSize(0.5, strm, targetFile, Image_name);
         }
```

Comment: How does that enforce a limit of 103x32?

Answer (score 0):

```
   // Fixed Size Image Generate Code
 protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

 decimal size = Math.Round(((decimal)fUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength / (decimal)1024), 2);
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(MapPath("Images"));
        FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
         foreach (FileInfo info in files)
        {
              decimal size2 = Math.Round(((decimal)info.Length / (decimal)1024), 2);
              string Image_name = info.Name.ToString();
              string targetPath = Server.MapPath("Images/" + Image_name);
              string strm = Server.MapPath("Images/" + Image_name);
              var targetFile = targetPath;
              ReduceImageSize(0.5, strm, targetFile, Image_name);
         }
}

 public void ReduceImageSize(double scaleFactor, String sourcePath, string targetPath, string Image_name)
    {

 // Fixed Size Image Generate Code

       public void ReduceImageSize(double scaleFactor, String sourcePath, string targetPath, string Image_name)
    {
        using (var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(sourcePath))
               {

            //var newWidth = (int)(image.Width  * scaleFactor);
            //var newHeight = (int)(image.Height * scaleFactor);
            var newWidth = (int)(500 * scaleFactor);
            var newHeight = (int)(500 * scaleFactor);
            var thumbnailImg = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
            var thumbGraph = Graphics.FromImage(thumbnailImg);
            thumbGraph.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            thumbGraph.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            thumbGraph.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            var imageRectangle = new System.Drawing.RectangleF (0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
            thumbGraph.DrawImage(image, imageRectangle);


            MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream();
            thumbnailImg.Save(s, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            s.Position = 0;
            byte[] image2 = new byte[525000];// 512kb =525000  
            s.Read(image2, 0, image2.Length);

            Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
            string Server_MapPath = Server.MapPath("~/Image Compress/" + Image_name + guid.ToString() + ".PNG");//Your Compressor Image Save Path

            System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(Server_MapPath, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            fs.Write(image2, 0, image2.Length);

        }
    }
```