# How to remove black border around transparent image in PDF created by iText

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

I have searched over bunch of sites, and I was unable to find solution for my problem.

This is the problem:
I am making PDF's in Java using iText library.
Everything works fine except one thing.
Transparent PNG images have black/gray border around non-transparent area.
I didn't set any borders in code, and actually I have tried to remove them (with no luck).

Can someone help me how to solve this problem?

The closest answer what I have found is: [Resizing an image in asp.net without losing the image quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319983/resizing-an-image-in-asp-net-without-losing-the-image-quality/2324414#2324414)
But I cannot (don't know) interpret this code in Java.

My code is pretty big to copy/paste, but these are steps:

1. create document
2. load image from given path
3. manipulate image (resize, rotate, positioning)
4. add image to current page
5. save pdf file

This is what I have tried also:

- http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/template/NamlServlet.jtp?macro=print_post&node=2157267
- http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/template/NamlServlet.jtp?macro=print_post&node=2330200
- I have tried more than those 2, but I didn't bookmarked them (none of them worked)

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:** I forgot to mention that my original pictures don't have border. Border is created somehow by iText. I initially thought that it was bug, but since iText 5.0.2 this problem remained so now I doubt that is bug (I am currently using 5.1.3).

**UPDATE 2** I forgot to add this link: http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/template/NamlServlet.jtp?macro=print_post&node=2157261
Here is presented VB script that works, but I cannot convert to Java code (it still draws black border), so can someone help me at least with this to convert good?

Comment: The answer is at https://stackoverflow.com/a/34506685/685806

Answer (score 0):

You could use the java BufferedImage method, `getSubImage(x, y, w, h)` which allows you to crop a sub image out of an existing image. That way you could cut out the edges.

See here: [Class BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but my original pictures don't have borders.