# Asp.net reduced image size in kb

Tags: asp.net, image-processing, thumbnails

I posted this other topic, got some gentle replies, but although the answers resolved the quality side of the question they created another issue with the image size in kb.
[Asp.net image resizing quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21367007/asp-net-image-resizing-quality)

Here is the issue.

I have a 2MB image that I want to reduce to 480px width.

I used three different ways to resize it:

1) On Fileupload ran this code:

```
System.IO.Stream st = FileUploadPost.PostedFile.InputStream;
myImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(st);
thumb = myImage.GetThumbnailImage(newWidth, newHeight, null, System.IntPtr.Zero);
thumb.Save(myPath);
```

Benefits: Size in kb becomes small (around 80Kb).

Downside: Visual quality is horrible

2) On Fileupload ran this code (solution provided on the mentioned post):

```
 Bitmap newImg = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight,    System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);                            
 Graphics newGraphic = Graphics.FromImage(newImg);
 newGraphic.DrawImage(myImage, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
 newGraphic.Dispose();
 newImg.Save(myPath);
```

Benefits: Visual quality is good

Downside: Size continues very big (around 400kb)

3) Used Windows Paint software and "manually" reduced the image to 480px width

Benefits: Benefits of both 1) and 2) -> Visual quality is good and size is reduced to around 80kb

Question is:

What is the code that reproduces item 3 behaviour (good visual quality and smaller size in kb)?

Thanks

Comment: Try http://imageresizing.net/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try one of these:

```
 Bitmap newImg = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb555);                            
 Graphics newGraphic = Graphics.FromImage(newImg);
 newGraphic.DrawImage(myImage, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
 newGraphic.Dispose();
 newImg.Save(myPath);
```

or

```
 Bitmap newImg = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppArgb1555);                            
 Graphics newGraphic = Graphics.FromImage(newImg);
 newGraphic.DrawImage(myImage, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
 newGraphic.Dispose();
 newImg.Save(myPath);
```

or

```
 Bitmap newImg = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);                            
 Graphics newGraphic = Graphics.FromImage(newImg);
 newGraphic.DrawImage(myImage, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
 newGraphic.Dispose();
 newImg.Save(myPath);
```

This should only slightly degrade the quality and drastically reduce the size, Im not sure which one would be better though.

Here are a whole bunch of other options to try as well:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: hey man! this really worked! many thanks!!! your first option above reduced the image to 193kb (half the size I was getting previously) and visually speaking quality remains the same. Got an error for options 2 and 3. Will try the other ones of your link too. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //BR**
        string filePath = "";//Source file path with image name
        int CompressLevel = 50;//Image compression leve as per our requirement
        string DestintionPath = "";//Destination file path
        string Filename = "";//Output image name to save in destination path

        Stream bmpStream = System.IO.File.Open(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
        Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(bmpStream);

        ImageCodecInfo jpgEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder myEncoder = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;
        EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
        EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, CompressLevel);
        myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
        bmp1.Save(DestintionPath + "\\" + Filename, jpgEncoder, myEncoderParameters);
        //BR**
        bmpStream.Close();
        string lblmsg = "Compressed Sucessfully with Compression Level { " + CompressLevel.ToString() + " }";
    }

    private ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)
    {
        /*/ Hope this will work.Thanks in advance /*/
        ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();

        foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)
        {
            if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid)
            {
                return codec;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```