# creating thumbnail gives very poor quality image

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I am creating thumbnail of Image file but it gives very poor quality image. please suggest me the way to improve the quality of thumbnail. my function is given below-

```
 public Image RezizeI(Image img, int maxW, int maxH)
    {
        if (img.Height < maxH && img.Width < maxW) return img;
        using (img)
        {
            Double xRatio = (double)img.Width / maxW;
            Double yRatio = (double)img.Height / maxH;
            Double ratio = Math.Max(xRatio, yRatio);
            int nnx = (int)Math.Floor(img.Width / ratio);
            int nny = (int)Math.Floor(img.Height / ratio);
            Bitmap cpy = new Bitmap(nnx, nny, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(cpy))
            {
                gr.Clear(Color.Transparent);

                // This is said to give best quality when resizing images
                gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

                gr.DrawImage(img,
                    new Rectangle(0, 0, nnx, nny),
                    new Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height),
                    GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            }
            return cpy;
        }
    }
```

for example my original image is 
[image]

and created thumbnail is- 
[image]

Comment: by poor quality do you mean the change in W:H ratio?

Comment: no that's not the problem. the problem is quality i.e. the image looking like made of small  dots. I dont know what it is exactly called may be the pixels. as you are seeing in thumb image.

Comment: no same problem is occuring

Comment: First, it looks like you have different proportions for the thumbnail.  Second, expect a lower quality image when reducing the size of the image. A thumbnail is what it is, a thumbnail. You are supposed to show a thumbnail on a smaller screen area where the reduction in image quality will not be relevant.

Comment: Try the other properties that are used [in the non-accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2324414/578411) where you copied that on that same question you got your code from...

Comment: @rene I tried that code also but the same error persists.

Comment: ok now I got what the problem is. when I store these thumbs locally, they are perfect but when I save them as a blob on azure blob storage, the quality degrades. but the real image quality remains same. Please help me regarding this.

Comment: I have managed it to upload asynchronously on azure. now the thumbnails are perfect. Thank you everyone for your support.

Answer (score 0):

I can't guarantee it, but the code I've used in the past to create better quality thumbnails includes these two lines...

```
gr.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
gr.PixelOffsetMode = Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
```