# Resize image before saving it to folder c# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, ajax, file-upload, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to resize an image that will be uploaded through a file input before saving it to the directed folder. I tried many possible way but i still cant get it. Please do help me!

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFile", "Upload", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{ 
     <input type="file" name="file" id="btnFileUpload" class="zone" runat="server"/>
}
```

Ajax

```
$('#btnFileUpload').fileupload({
                    url: '@Url.Action("UploadFile")',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
                        .test(window.navigator && navigator.userAgent),
},
            success: function (e, data) {
                //window.location.reload();
                console.log("Done");
                console.log(e);
});
```

controller

```
[HttpPost]  
        public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)  
        {
            string _FileName = "";
            string _path = "";
         try  
            {
               if (file.ContentLength > 0)  
                {
                    _FileName = Path.GetFileName(DateTime.Now.ToBinary() + "-" + file.FileName);
                    _path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles"), _FileName);

                    file.SaveAs(_path);


                    imageUrls = "/UploadedFiles/" + _FileName;
                }
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("File Uploaded Successfully!!");

                return Json(imageUrls);
            }  
            catch
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "File upload failed!!";
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("File upload failed!!");
                return Json(ViewBag.Message);  
            }  
        }
```

Comment: what you tried?

Comment: I tried webimage and ajax process

Comment: i cannot seen any resize image code in you questions

Comment: just google "Resize image in c#"

Comment: may be this answer work for you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319983/resizing-an-image-in-asp-net-without-losing-the-image-quality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here The Implementation of Your scenario

i think this will work

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UploadFile (HttpPostedFileBase file) {

            string _FileName = "";
            string _path = "";
            try {
                if (file.ContentLength > 0) {
                    _FileName = Path.GetFileName (DateTime.Now.ToBinary () + "-" + file.FileName);
                    _path = Path.Combine (Server.MapPath ("~/UploadedFiles"), _FileName);
                    byte[] fileData = null;
                    using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader (file.InputStream)) {
                        fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes (file.ContentLength);
                    }

                    HandleImageUpload (fileData, _path);

                    imageUrls = "/UploadedFiles/" + _FileName;
                }
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine ("File Uploaded Successfully!!");

                return Json (imageUrls);
            } catch {
                ViewBag.Message = "File upload failed!!";
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine ("File upload failed!!");
                return Json (ViewBag.Message);
            }
        }

        private Image RezizeImage (Image img, int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
            if (img.Height < maxHeight && img.Width < maxWidth) return img;
            using (img) {
                Double xRatio = (double) img.Width / maxWidth;
                Double yRatio = (double) img.Height / maxHeight;
                Double ratio = Math.Max (xRatio, yRatio);
                int nnx = (int) Math.Floor (img.Width / ratio);
                int nny = (int) Math.Floor (img.Height / ratio);
                Bitmap cpy = new Bitmap (nnx, nny, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
                using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage (cpy)) {
                    gr.Clear (Color.Transparent);

                    // This is said to give best quality when resizing images
                    gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

                    gr.DrawImage (img,
                        new Rectangle (0, 0, nnx, nny),
                        new Rectangle (0, 0, img.Width, img.Height),
                        GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                }
                return cpy;
            }

        }

        private MemoryStream BytearrayToStream (byte[] arr) {
            return new MemoryStream (arr, 0, arr.Length);
        }

        private void HandleImageUpload (byte[] binaryImage, string path) {
            Image img = RezizeImage (Image.FromStream (BytearrayToStream (binaryImage)), 103, 32);
            img.Save (path, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.jpg);
        }
```

resize Code taken from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319983/resizing-an-image-in-asp-net-without-losing-the-image-quality)

Comment: oh cool it's working! but how do i change the image height and width according to my liking?

Comment: it's okay i found it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are many great libraries for this task that handle everything you need.

I personally use [ImageProcessor](http://imageprocessor.org/). And I know a ton more exist with same or even better quality. If you want I can help you use it but the documentation should be enough.

**--Edit--**

This is a sample code to use ImageProcessor see if it helps:

```
var imageFactory = new ImageFactory(true);
imageFactory.Load(inputStream).Resize(
    new ResizeLayer(new Size(128, 128), ResizeMode.Max)).
    Save(path);
```

Also don't forget to install the  required nuget package :)

Comment: i tried that too but apparently, i can't seem to use ImageProcessor.

Comment: Ok now tell me what the problem was. You don't know how to use it or you did and got error or something?

Comment: erm there is no lib for image processor as well or image resizer

Comment: I didn't understand what `there is no lib for ...` means but see the edit.

Comment: oh I paste the codes in and they cannot find what is ImageFactory, ResizeMode and path...

Comment: Right click the project, select `Manage nuget packages` search for ImageProcessor. Click install. Add `using ImageProcessor;` and `using ImageProcessor.Imaging;` to the file where you paste my code.

Comment: ImageProcessor is external third party library.you need to accept the terms and condtions to use the library.http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Comment: Yes there are other libraries with different licences

Comment: After i run the codes there still error though. But it's okay now i found other answer but thank you for you time @Emad