# cropping image using js and mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm sending collection of images trough webform using MVC3. Controller receiving this posted images and save it's name into db.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(MyViewModel data, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> postedImages)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      using (session...and transaction...)
      {
         MyModel model = session.Get<MyModel>(data.Id);                           
         data.SendToDomainModel(model, session);                     
         foreach (var image in postedImages)
         {
            if ((image != null) && (image.ContentLength > 0))
            {
                Photo photo = new Photo();
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(image.FileName);
                // path used to save actuall image to the hdd path
                var pathToSave = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/uploads"), fileName);
                // path used to save image path inside db column
                var path = Path.Combine("/Content/uploads/" + fileName);
                photo.MyModel= session.Load<MyModel>(model.Id);
                photo.Path = path;
                photo.Name = fileName;
                image.SaveAs(pathToSave);
                model.Photos.Add(photo);
              }
           }
           // commit transaction ..
           // save session ..
       }
       return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else { return View(data); }
}
```

How can I use first image from image collection and copy that with filename prefix "firstImage" and crop to 50x50px dimension?

Thanks

Comment: You want to crop or resize?  Do you want JS that will allow the user to select the area to crop to?

Comment: Actually I do not need JS, sorry. Just crop to exact dimension.

Comment: Crop 50px x 50px from the center of the image?  I'm trying to make sure we are using the same definition for crop.

Comment: This type of question has been asked several times, does this help?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662080/how-to-efficiently-scale-and-crop-images-in-an-asp-net-app#answer-8163392

Comment: I'm at the very end of my workday, so I'm out of focus. You're right, I do need resizing without croping. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, non-optimized resizing can be acheived using System.Drawing's [`GetThumbnailImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.getthumbnailimage.aspx)

Example:

```
Image thumb=image.GetThumbnailImage(50, 50, null, IntPtr.Zero);
```

For a more optimized method that doesn't have [the pitfalls listed here](http://www.nathanaeljones.com/blog/2009/20-image-resizing-pitfalls) see:

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662080/how-to-efficiently-scale-and-crop-images-in-an-asp-net-app#answer-8163392)

Comment: That pitfalls article is very interesting